# Where does Iptables store blocked IPs

Tags: iptables

I need to set up a shell to block DDOS attacks , but in that script, it's reading some Blocked IPs from `/etc/sysconfig/iptables`.

The problem is that I don't have this directory, So I'm wondering where should I read the blocked IPs from.

I followed [this script by Mr Takefuji](http://linuxgazette.net/137/takefuji.html). I'm using Debian 7 and have never set Iptables untill now.

Comment: If you need to block many IPs, using [IPset](http://ipset.netfilter.org/index.html) instead of many iptables rules is more efficient. You can get an recent list of suspicious IPs from  http://rules.emergingthreats.net/open/snort-2.9.0/rules/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That directory is a Red Hat/Fedora/RHEL directory so I wouldn't expect it to be on any other distributions of Linux. Here's what's in that file on my Fedora 14 system:

```
# Firewall configuration written by system-config-firewall
# Manual customization of this file is not recommended.
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m udp -p udp --dport 631 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m udp -p udp --dport 5353 -d 224.0.0.251 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 631 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m udp -p udp --dport 631 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
COMMIT
```

Most distros keep this information in different locations, I would determine where Debian keeps it and put this info there. The upside to using a file like this is that it's configured to be used when the iptables "service" is stopped & started.

Again on Fedora the service is this:

```
$ service iptables start
```

When that is invoked the file I referenced above is used to establish firewall rules as described in that file.

#### Going it alone

If you just want to setup your own rules you don't have to use that service, it's a convenience at the end of the day. You can run `iptables` rules directly. In fact if you look at the format of the file referenced above you'll notice that they are just the contents of a call to `iptables`:

```
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

If you're new to `iptables` you might find a tool such as [firestarter](http://www.fs-security.com/) easier to getting going with its setup.

Comment: The file is here : /var/lib/iptables